# send scancode to my application 

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a question about scan code and extended 
OK .

I create a simple window in c++ and I want to detect WM_KEYUP only ( VK_UP value )

Now I run spy++ and I press up key I detect my message like this

```
keydown  vk_up    crepeat1     scancode 48     extended1      altdown0     frepeat1      up0
```

Now if I send a message to my application I get the following message

```
SendMessage ( wnd , WM_KEYDOWN , VK_UP ,1);

keydown  vk_up    crepeat1     scancode 00     extended0      altdown0     frepeat1      up0
```

You see the different in scan code and other value.

My question is why this different even I send the same message?
2 is there any way to send scan code ( and other value to my application and get the same value )

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the difference but you can use [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to synthesize keystrokes.

Comment: thank you , but keybd_event or SendInput both send value to other window i want to specify message to my application only

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for WM_KEYDOWN.  The scan code is contained in bits 16 through 23 in the LPARAM argument.  You passed 1, the scan code bits are thus all zero.

This is okayish, there are not a lot of apps that actually check the scancode.  Using SendMessage() is however not correct, keyboard messages go into the message queue.  You should use PostMessage().  The difference is that many message loops look at keystrokes to implement accelerators (aka shortcut keys).  And call TranslateMesssage() to turn WM_KEYDOWN messages in WM_CHAR messages for typing keys.

There's another problem, an unsolvable one, you cannot control the state of the keyboard.  The Ctrl, Alt and Shift modifiers.  If the user happens to have the, say, Shift key pressed, the app will see Shift+Up, it may well interpret it very differently, editors certainly do.  Only using SendInput() is a cure for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SendMessage ( wnd , WM_KEYDOWN , VK_UP ,0x00480001);
```